# Check for the existence of a key in a JSON coming from server

Tags: javascript

In pure JavaScript I want to check for the existence of a JSON key. The JSON is in the following form (I simplify):

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":"","d":"t"}}}
```

I must check for the existence of "c" (`a.b.c`) because under some circumstances the server returns a JSON containing "d" but not "c".

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `/"c":/.test(strResponse)`

Comment: Please @dandavis, could you expand a little?

Comment: @dandavis, this would check for the presence of `"c"` anywhere, including at other levels or as a value.

Comment: You want to check just `c` or that `c` is inside `a.b`?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski: that c is inside a.b of course!  :-)

Comment: @dandavis: sorry for not explaining better: of course, I should search for c inside a.b

Comment: @jcaron: it can't match values because inner quotes would be escaped; so there's only one way that it would match...

Comment: I hadn't noticed the `:` so it would indeed not match a value, but it would definitely match **any** key named `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you parse json with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can use `Object.keys()` and `indexOf()`

```js
var data = {"a":{"b":{"c":"","d":"t"}}}
var result = Object.keys(data.a.b).indexOf('c') != -1;
console.log(result)
```

Or you can check for key with `hasOwnProperty`

```js
var data = {"a":{"b":{"c":"","d":"t"}}}

if(data.a.b.hasOwnProperty('c')) console.log('True')
```

Answer (score 2):

i assume that server response is already parsed in to js object

```
var abc = {"a":{"b":{"c":"","d":"t"}}};
if(abc.a.b.hasOwnProperty("c")){
 // do something
}else{
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: This is often a good option, but beware that if `abc.a.b.c` is falsy (e.g. its value is 0 or an empty string), you'll end up doing the same as if it wasn't there at all.

Comment: @jcaron: this is EXACTLY why I came here! I was looking for a different approach

Comment: @3000 you can simplify it by `return a && a.b && a.b.c` – it will provide value of `c` only if whole object / structure exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string with the properties to check for and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
function check(object, path) {
    return path.split('.').every(function (k) {
        if (k in this.o) {
            this.o = this.o[k];
            return true;
        }
    }, { o: object });
}

var object = { a: { b: { c: "", d: "t" } } };

console.log(check(object, 'a.b.c'));
console.log(check(object, 'y.b.c'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fnIsExist(o,key2Search){
  var exist = false;
  for(var k in o){
     if(k == key2Search){
      exist = true;
    }else{
       if( typeof o[k] == 'object'){
         exist = fnIsExist(o[k],key2Search);
        }
    }
  }  
  return exist;
}

var obj = {"a":{"b":{"c":"","d":"t"}}};
var key = 'd';
var isExist = fnIsExist(obj,key); 
console.log(isExist);
```

see jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zguubym3/